# Change Imageview PNG in a timed loop

Tags: android, animation, timer, png

I have a png sequence that I want to display in an imageview. It has 745 frames of up to 44kb each and want to play it at 23 fps. Some of the frames have are different from the previous frame or are blank so I could skip updating on frames 100-243 and 340-400 for example. So the total size on disk ends up around 9mb (I only use need to use 249 images out of the 745 frames beacuase there are some pauses in the animation and some times the animation object goes off screen). All images are 320 x 480 and are scaled to fit the screen.

While it's playing I need to do some other stuff along the way without stopping the animation.
I'm new to Java. In pseudocode I would like to do something like this :

The Activity loads...

For x = 1 to 745

```
if exsists("image" & x) then 
    imageview setbackground("image" & x) (change this every 35ms)

switch (x)
case: 10 then call a function at frame 10
case: 100 then call a function that vibrates 0.5sec at frame  100
case: 200 then call different function at frame 200
```

Loop

End the animation...

Then close the Activty.

So the question is how to do this on the Android?

I tried using an AnimationDrawable and an animationlist.xml array but get a Simulator VM Error if I have more than 40 frames.
I can get a little bit more to run on the actual device.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be apprieciated.

Comment: thats more than 30mb of frames you want to keep in memory. Its not possible to do that on most devices. You can try to recycle old Bitmaps you no longer use or look into VideoView

Comment: If I only use the frames that change I can get the total size down to 9mb (245 different images used over in a loop of 745). How do I recycle? I only want to use each frame once. I have this working on the iPhone. Infact I have 2 sequences. one with transparent png files (9mb) and another with jpgs (no trasparency using 5.7mb). The user can choose which one to play. Can anyone help with the looping question so I can try it with smaller number of  images. On the iPhone I use a [self performSelector:@selector(playimages) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.035]; Total App size ends up at 18mb.

Comment: no tags in subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution I was looking for the Timed Loop although it does bring up a new issue regarding my frame rate requirements which I have included in a new question.

If you only need to update images every 70ms then this solution seems to work without the same memory restrictions as AnimationDrawable.

See new question at:

[750 frame transparent PNG animation in ImageView at 23fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528116/750-frame-transparent-png-animation-in-imageview-at-23fps)